# Swiping Past Last Tab App Crashes

Tags: crash, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

I'm using ActionBarSherlock with a ViewPager with navigation mode set to display my tabs.  I have 3 tabs that work fine.  My problem is that if I were to try to swipe to a non-existant 4th tab it crashes my app.  I'm not sure where this is happening, need some help.  This is my first attempt at an app, any feedback is welcome.

fragments:

```
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

private SherlockFragment mFragCodes;
private SherlockFragment mFragDeals;
private SherlockFragment mFragProgInfo;
private SherlockFragment mFragTemp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new MainPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager()));
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    //mViewPager.setPageMarginDrawable(R.drawable.border);
    mViewPager.setPageMargin(16);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(R.string.tab_codes_title)
            .setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(R.string.tab_deals_title)
            .setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(R.string.tab_program_info_title)
            .setTabListener(this));
```

and my pageradapter:

```
    private class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MainPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public SherlockFragment getItem(int position) {


        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return (mFragCodes = new frag_codes());

        case 1:
            return (mFragDeals = new frag_deals());

        case 2:
            return (mFragProgInfo = new frag_programming());

        }
        //if nothing is returned
        return mFragTemp = new SherlockFragment();
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
         return R.string.tab_count;
    }
}
```

Any other info I should include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go over [Swipey Tabs example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZN496pmtS8) and the example included in the samples folder that comes with the ActionBarSherlock library (FragmentTabsPager) to see working examples of a tabs adapter.
Furthermore, please include additional info, mostly the stack trace from the exception, the layouts and the full classes including the declaration and imports.

From what I see you are missing the `implements` part where you should be implementing `ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`.

Answer (score 1):

Just put:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
     return 3;
}
```